# About conversion specifier in C

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I have a question about conversion specifier in C.

In the 5th sentence if I use `%lf` or `%Lf` instead of `%f`, no error occurs. But why does error happen if I use `%f`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long double num;
    printf("value: ");
    scanf("%f",&num);  // If I use %lf or %Lf instead of %f, no error occurs. 
    printf("value: %f \n",num);
}
```

Comment: So you ask why you get a compiler warning if you use the wrong specifier? Please step back and read your question again. Then get a C book and start learning from the very first page.

Comment: @Olaf This is actually a confusing subject to learn, because `%f` means different things in `printf` vs `scanf`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: And in my own functions it might mean something even more different. Anyway, that is about `long double` where there is no difference. `printf` acception `double` for `%f` is just a legacy and just because you cannot pass a `float` parameter to a variadic function. Imo it is straight forward. Just use `%f` for `float` arguments, `%lf` for `double` in both functions (`logn double` is already clear). Does not sound very confusing to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%f` is meant to be used for reading `float`s, not `double`s or `long double`s.

`%lf` is meant to be used for reading `double`s.

`%Lf` is meant to be used for reading `long double`s.

If your program works with `%lf` when the variable type is `long double`, it's only a coincidence. It works probably because `sizeof(double)` is the same as `sizeof(long double)` on your platform. In theory, it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In looking at the man page for `printf(3)` on a FreeBSD system (which is POSIX, by the way), I get the following:

> The following length modifier is valid for the `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`,
>            or `G` conversion:
>
> ```
>      Modifier    a, A, e, E, f, F, g, G
>      l (ell)     double (ignored, same behavior as without it)
>      L           long double
> ```

I have used the conversions with a 32-bit float data type.  But the issue here is that the reason is because different float formats have different sizes, and the `printf` function needs to know which one it is so it can properly make that conversion.  Using `%Lf` on a float may cause a segmentation error because the conversion is accessing data outside the variable, so you get undefined behavior.

- float: 32-bit
- double: 64-bit
- long double: 80-bit

Now for the `long double`, the actual size is defined by the platform and the implementation.  80 bits is 10 bytes, but that doesn't exactly fit within a 32-bit alignment without padding.  So most implementations use either 96-bits or 128-bits (12 bytes or 16 bytes respectively) to set the alignment.

Be careful here though, just because it might take 128-bits doesn't mean that it is a `__float128` (if using gcc or clang).  There is at least one platform where specifying `long double` does mean a `__float128` (SunOS, I think), but it is implemented in software and is slow. Furthermore, some compilers (Microsoft and Intel come to mind) `long double` = `double` unless you specify a switch on the command line.